# Looking for a sigmoid-like function with different properties

Tags: functions, continuity, real-numbers

I am looking for a function that is 0 at 0, 1 at 1, increases to a predetermined $x_1$ relatively quickly, acquires a derivative close to 0 (but doesn't actually plateau) then starts increasing at $x_2$, and it is infinitely differentiable.

To give you an idea of what I mean, consider the function:

$x^{1/n} (1-t) + (x^2)^st$

(see it on desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hb8rjdzqm5)

This function obeys the properties that it is 0 at 0, 1 at 1, and it also has a low derivative in the mid-range. However, it is not possible to specify an $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that the plateaued region is contained within the interval $[x_1, x_2]$.